# Tooltip not working well based on array id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tooltip

What I am trying to do is to make the "tooltip" work in this way:

When I click on some "link" with X id it will show the "tooltip" text based on "element" id I have set in my array.

The problem now is that when I create a new link with the id of the second or the third array its still shows me the the first one

My code:

```
var wp_button_pointer_array = new Array();
wp_button_pointer_array[1] = {
    'element' : 'wp-button-pointer',
    'options' : {
        'content': 'The HTML content to show inside the pointer', 
        'position': {'edge': 'top', 'align': 'center'} 
    } 
}; 
wp_button_pointer_array[2] = { 
    'element' : 'some-element-id', 
    'options' : { 
        'content': 'The HTML content to show inside the pointer', 
        'position': {'edge': 'top', 'align': 'center'} 
    }
};


jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    jQuery('.wp-button-pointer-open-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if(typeof(jQuery().pointer) != 'undefined') { // make sure the pointer class exists

            if(jQuery('.wp-pointer').is(":visible")) { // if a pointer is already open...
                var openid = jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').attr("id").replace('wp-pointer-',''); // ... note its id
                jQuery('#' + wp_button_pointer_array[openid].element).pointer('close'); // ... and close it
                var pointerid = parseInt(openid) + 1;
            } else {
                var pointerid = 1; // ... otherwise we want to open the first pointer
            }

        }
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be on this line

```
var openid = jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').attr("id").replace('wp-pointer-','');
```

1) It may be possible that the first one is not actually hidden but covered by the new one. The `attr()` function is only going to get the attribute of the first matched element. To troubleshoot you could add `console.log(jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').length);` to see if only one element is being returned.

2) Ensure that when you are creating the new ones, that you are keeping the same ID pattern ("wp-pointer-#") and that the number - represented by the # symbol - is changing. To troubleshoot you could add `console.log(jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').attr("id"));` to see if the ID is what you are expecting it to be.

**update**

If the problem is with `var pointerid = 1;` and you need to get the id of the element that was clicked, I think you can do it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    jQuery('.wp-button-pointer-open-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if(typeof(jQuery().pointer) != 'undefined') { 
            if(jQuery('.wp-pointer').is(":visible")) { /
                var openid = jQuery('.wp-pointer:visible').attr("id").replace('wp-pointer-',''); 
                jQuery('#' + wp_button_pointer_array[openid].element).pointer('close'); 
                var pointerid = parseInt(openid) + 1;
            } else {
                var pointerid  = 1; //default
                var clickedId = $(e.target).attr("id");

                for (var i in wp_button_pointer_array) {
                    if (wp_button_pointer_array[i].element === clickedId) {
                        pointerid = i;
                        break; //exit the for loop
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });         
});
```

Comment: Hi,
the problem seems to be here: var pointerid = 1;
how can i change from "1" to number from array based on element id that was clicked?

Comment: You may be able to use `$(e.target)`. `e.target` gets the DOM element that was actually clicked.

Comment: HI, ok i know the solution but i need your help to make this work!
var pointer id = 1; that's why it show always first "pointer". i create function that will store the id of the clicked element. what i need is to search in all the arrays if the id = element if yes, i need to get the array id and put this id number in the var pointerid = (id number from array);

Comment: for example: clicked id = test, so if 'element' : 'test', = clicked id give me wp_button_pointer_array[2] - here the id of the array is 2. so var pointerid = 2;